# fcm_django.FCMDevice.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User'

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, hybrid-mobile-app

In this project, I've used fcm-django package for push notifications in the flutter app. And I have got the following error though I've set up appropriately. Please help me what I wrote wrong!

```
fcm_django.FCMDevice.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
    HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

**Here is my fcm-settings:**

```
# FIREBASE_APP = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

FCM_DJANGO_SETTINGS = {
    # default: _('FCM Django')
    "APP_VERBOSE_NAME": "django_fcm",
    # Your firebase API KEY
    "FCM_SERVER_KEY": "AAAAGhkzsi8:APA91bGCGga9FZnwASRy8NtLpp7jpINJcWbUiz9EHOFIxJjla8yVlpGtdqL7QB5rII0vKKExkpUw9PuRHt6khrpgcqDxcbzQvCWzgsBmT4SRRfoCirpGFXETIdIetgxBvktKJYSdjf_O",
    # true if you want to have only one active device per registered user at a time
    # default: False
    "ONE_DEVICE_PER_USER": False,
    # devices to which notifications cannot be sent,
    # are deleted upon receiving error response from FCM
    # default: False
    "DELETE_INACTIVE_DEVICES": True,
}

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'FcmDjangoConfig.default_auto_field'
```

**And, I also imported the following lines:**

```
from fcm_django.apps import FcmDjangoConfig

firebase_admin.initialize_app()
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './push_notification/serviceAccountKey.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

As the fcm_django_fcmdevice model has a FK field user that is related to the authenticated user. So,if you have defined a custom user model just add the following line to your settings.py file
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_App_name.CustomUserModelName'